# Should I use Facebook Share Dialog or Feed Dialog? I'd need to redirect users to another page after succcessfull response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm making a very simple site where users can do a silly little test, and share the result to Facebook. After visitor shares they should be redirected to another page on the site.

I've gotten it working using the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3) but it seems like the [Share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) is recommended and somehow maybe better?

So:

- How are Share dialog and Feed dialog different?
- Which one should I use for what purpose?
- Is it possible to redirect the user to a new page after successful share with the Share dialog? It says that the ID of response data is "Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted `publish_actions`. If present, this is the ID of the published Open Graph story."

Here is the code I'm using (Feed Dialog). What we share will depend on the the results of the test the user did.

```
function share_prompt() {
    FB.ui(
       {
         method: 'feed',
         name: fbName,
         link: fbLink,
         picture: fbPictureUrl,
         caption: fbCaption,
         description: fbDescription,
         message: fbMessage
       },
       function(response) {
         if (response && response.post_id) {
           //alert('Post was published.');
           alert('redirect to a page-->');
           window.location.href = "http://redirect-user-here.com";
         } else {
           alert('User didin't share the story, we'll do something else);

         }
       }
     ); //FB.ui
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

- The Feed Dialog allowed to set your own custom data, the Share Dialog takes the Open Graph tags from the shared URL.
- Debug the callback of the Share Dialog when you cancel the Share and when you approve it. But you should not redirect users after Sharing, maybe they want to use the Share Dialog again to share the URL in another channel.

Comment: How do you know that the Feed Dialog is deprecated? I couldn't see that mentioned on the [Facebook doc page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4).